# Why does my fluorescent lighting only work when it's not hot outside?

Tags: repair, lighting, temperature

We have fluorescent lights in our kitchen and when it's over 75°F outside the lights turn on real dim like there might be a problem with the ballasts, but when the outside temperature drops the lights come on fine.

Does anyone have an idea at what might need to be replaced?

Comment: Is it just that one fixture?

Comment: What is the inside temperature? Are the lights inside or outside?

Answer (score 1):

When florescent tubes get close to the end of their service life, they can behave unpredictably.  Double check for any darkening of the glass near the pins.  If you have a spare bulb that you know is good, try swapping the lamp and see if there is any improved performance.

Answer (score 0):

The fluorescent lights can't work normally outside with 75°F.  maybe replace your ballasts can fix the issue.  Some IC will protection the ballast if working temperature high. 75°F is low temperature.

Or replace the fluorescent lights with led light directly.  LED fluorescent light is energy saving,  18w can replace 40w.  no ballasts requirement.  You can connect the led fluorescent light with 220v/110v directly.

For kitchen, if replace fluorescent lights with led light,  please kindly care the CRI more than 85%.   If lower CRI,  you will find the food is not good to see.

Hope this can help you.